# Liferay Hook calling extension method

Tags: liferay

I have new action in a liferay hook which ideally will be calling methods created in an extension. But at run time when executing the action, it throws the exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
 for the methods created in the extension.
Has anybody created similar action in liferay hook? if so, what was the solution for this problem if encountered?

Here is my code:

```
public class ExampleStrutsAction extends BaseStrutsAction { 
    public String execute( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String name = ParamUtil.get(request, "name", "World");
        ThemeDisplay themeDisplay= (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
        BSCDynamicDataListLocalServiceUtil.cloneDynamicDataListPageInSuborganization(the‌​meDisplay, name);
        return "/portal/sample.jsp"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: my action is very basic, just trying to call the method in my extension, and it is failing due to the ClassNotFound exception:

Comment: Can you please show your very basic method. Its not possible to answer without seeing that..

Comment: public class ExampleStrutsAction extends BaseStrutsAction {

    public String execute(
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

        String name = ParamUtil.get(request, "name", "World");

      
        
        ThemeDisplay  themeDisplay= (ThemeDisplay) request.getAttribute(WebKeys.THEME_DISPLAY);
BSCDynamicDataListLocalServiceUtil.cloneDynamicDataListPageInSuborganization(themeDisplay,  name);
      
        return "/portal/sample.jsp";
    }

}

Comment: I could not post it in the answers since I am a new member, sorry

Comment: In `portal-hook.properties`, your must register this hook. Have you done that? I have this `portal-hook.properties` under resources folder of my java source file.

Comment: is BSCDynamicDataListLocalServiceUtil a custom service you've built ? if yes, you'll have to copy that service jar in tomcal/lib/ext

Comment: @NaseelaAmdeeb You can _always_ edit your own posts.

Comment: Also include the stacktrace of the exception

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,

hook.xml

```
<hook>
    <portal-properties>portal.properties</portal-properties>
    <language-properties>
        content/Language.properties
    </language-properties>
    <custom-jsp-dir>/META-INF/custom_jsps</custom-jsp-dir>
    <struts-action>
        <struts-action-path>/my_account/edit_user</struts-action-path>
        <struts-action-impl>com.test.hook.action.EditUserAction</struts-action-impl>
    </struts-action>
    <struts-action>
        <struts-action-path>/users_admin/edit_user</struts-action-path>
        <struts-action-impl>com.test.hook.action.EditUserAction</struts-action-impl>
    </struts-action>

</hook>
```

EditUserAction class

```
public class EditUserAction extends BaseStrutsPortletAction
{
    @Override
    public void processAction(final StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction, final PortletConfig portletConfig,
            final ActionRequest actionRequest, final ActionResponse actionResponse) throws Exception
    {
        // add your custom code
        originalStrutsPortletAction.processAction(portletConfig, actionRequest, actionResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(final StrutsPortletAction originalStrutsPortletAction, final PortletConfig portletConfig, final RenderRequest renderRequest,
            final RenderResponse renderResponse) throws Exception
    {
        //add your custom code
        return originalStrutsPortletAction.render(portletConfig, renderRequest, renderResponse);
    }
```

}

I have created above hook for EditUserAction in Control Panel
Hope it helps you!!